# How to properly position a image?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in html and css, and I am trying to position an image like shown in this dribble (https://dribbble.com/shots/2314157-Daily-UI-Day-1/attachments/439137). I can use some help since I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code.

.html file

```
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <p class="caption">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <h1>Become a member</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam/</p>
      <button>Sign Up with Google+</button>
      <button>Sign Up with Facebook</button>
      <button>Sign Up with Twitter</button>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Use your email</a>
    </section>
    <aside>
      <img src='http://i.imgur.com/MvG7aI0.jpg'>
    </aside>
  </div>
```

and .css file

```
    body {
      background-color: #4c505d;
    }

    .container {
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 12% 14%;
      width: 76%;
    }
    section {
      width: 64.5%;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make the section float left and aside float right. But you don't really need the aside, just put the image there.

And you should specify the width of the section so aside won't be below the section. Specify it in percentages.

```
section {
  float: left;
}

aside {
  float: left;
}
```

To aside add height 100% and width auto to maintain image size. And put position fixed so there will be no scrolling and right: 0 so it will move to the right side of the page.

```
aside {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle file: https://jsfiddle.net/hmfc697r/